# String formatting in Dart

Tags: dart

I was looking up string classes and some other resources, trying to see how to format strings.  Primarily, I am trying to Pad out a number to a string, but not precision.

example:

```
 int a = 0, b = 5, c = 15, d = 46;
 String aout = "", bout = "", cout="", dout="";

 //aout = "00"
 //bout = "05"
 //cout = "15"
 //dout = "46"
```

When i was looking at int to fixed string precision, it was mostly when dealing with decimals and not prepended padding.

My original thought is that I could do something related to sprintf, such as:

```
String out = sprintf("%02d", a);
```

but that didnt seem to work, mostly because It was saying that i am getting a nosuchmethod error.  I was not sure if sprintf is in a different package other than core, as i thought this would be related directly to strings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a [String.padLeft](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/String/padLeft.html) method you can use:

```
String out = a.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Its better than what i was going to do:  `String out = (a<10)?"0$a":a;`